# Downconvert high voltage to match dry contact rating

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-divider

I have a few dry contacts on a device where the ratings are MAX 30V, 300mA.
I want to connect LED indicators (24V, 20mA) to these dry contacts and was thinking to setup an external 24V power supply to feed the LED indicators when dry contacts close.

However, there seem to be a reason for me to use 230V power supply, so I was wondering if it works using same LED indicators (24V, 20mA) and a resistor of 10kOhm in series?

$$U = U_1 + U_2 => U_2 = 230 - 24 = 206V $$
$$I = 20mA => R = U_2/I = 206V / 20mA = 10kOhm$$

I just get confused given the rating of dry contacts are given in volts... How should I know what voltage there is across the dry contact?
(Consider all components and supplies being AC.)

Comment: Dry contacts neither make nor break raw load currents,  so your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Uhmm... Well, let me say that your comment doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: That's probably because you don't understand the definition of "dry contact". Try Google to lead you to Wikipedia for clarification. I mean you no ill will, and you really should get your ducks in a row before you commit pen to paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you switch a circuit involving 230 VDC the contact voltage when open circuit will be 230 VDC, which is greatly in excess of 30 VDC.

**Contact voltage rating must be >= the voltage that will appear across the contacts when open circuit.**

If you are using 230 VAC mains as the source of HV DC and rectifying it then Vdc will usually be around 1.414 x V_AC_RMS = 230 x 1.414 ~= 325 VDC.
Your resistor will need adjusting accordingly.
eg (325-24)/20 mA = 15k

Dissipation in a series resistor = V x I
= 206V x 20 mA = 4.12W in the 230 VDC case or
= 301V x 20 mA = 6W in the 325 VDC case
A 10 W rated resistor is required at minimum in the 4W case and > 10W rated ideally in the 6W case.
The resistor MUST be rated for at least the full DC voltage used, regardless of power rating and any other losses.

IF AC is used as the 230 V source power dissipation can be greatly reduced by using a series capacitor to drop most of the voltage. Numerous capacitor dropper supply examples are available.

Use of HV DC in the manner you describe MAY make sense in some cases, but use of a transformer r similar to provide a low voltage supply usually will make more sense.

Comment: Some portions of your answer is very useful. But other parts mix AC and DC too much. As I stated at the end is that all components (including LED are AC). At least now I understand more that AC peaks need to be considered aswell...

Comment: @niCkcAMel I mixed AC and DC with clear distinctiomn between BECAUSE you appeared to be mixing them without realising you were doing so - and you seem now to confirm that you were doing as it appeared. eg if all voltages are AC AND you determine I_LED by using (230-V_LED)/I_LED then you MIGHT almost manage that with suitable design and low voltage rectification BUT if you are rectifying the AC to DC and then dropping it and if you are smoothing the HVDC then you need to use R ~= (VACRMS x sqrt(2) - VLED)/I_LED - as I know you realise now and MAYBE before.  ...

Comment: ... As it was unclear what you intended or understood I tried to "cover all bases", or at least make it clear what MY assumptions were. Failing to do so risked less clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit does not down convert enough.

The reverse voltage needs to be blocked with a diode or bridged with 4 diodes for less flicker.

The peak voltage exceeds 230Vac by 40% and the switched voltage far exceeds 24V.

A small opto-Thyristor would work with a 5W resistor.

EDIT

A doorbell or old furnace thermostat transformer @24V would be a better match.

Answer (score 1):

You could drop 206 VRMS across a 10k ohm resistor but you'd be dissipating a power of 0.02 amps X 0.02 amps x 10,000 ohms = 4 watts.

You might also break your LEDs because if the power supply is AC, you would likely exceed the maximum reverse voltage of the LED.

Also, it's highly unsafe doing it this way - consider using a transformer to provide the correct voltage and a bridge rectifier and capacitor if a DC supply is needed for the LED.

However, the bottom line is that if the contact rating is 30 V it SHOULD not be used in a circuit greater than 30 V.

Comment: If the LED says 24VAC then what would be the problem with reverse voltage?

Comment: Yes, I'm leaning more towards the transformer implementation. Tnx

Comment: @niCkcAMel If the "LED" says 24VAC then it is **PROBABLY NOT** an LED nor just a string of LEDs but may have rectification and may have smoothing. And, even if you used raw AC on LEDs they would flicker but may survive if Vpeak_AC < V_reverse_LED. BUT Vr_LED is usually not vastly > VfLED and it is fatal to exceed it. In your case using AC would apply ~~= 24 Vf due to IR drop if properly designed BUT would provide Vr ~= 300V. Them what dies would be the lucky ones.

Comment: I hear you... LED transformator is the way to go LOL. Looking for one as we speak.